# Is there an HTTP code example for the Olympus-air OPC

Tags: olympus-camerakit, olympus-air

Does the Olympus Air permit a client to control it over an HTTP/REST style API as with the Sony QX series cameras?

If so, are there any code examples showing how to establish any session required/authing and to start controlling the camera?

I'm searching for a manual providing detailed description of how the camera can be communicated with, expecting some kind of github repository because of the 'Open' designation in the name 'Open Camera Platform' but at the moment it doesn't feel that open as I can find so little information freely available.

Answer (score 5):

This kind of question should be sent to Olympus' contact:

https://opc.olympus-imaging.com/en/contact-us/

Here you can download the specification of communication protocol for Olympus Air. Not at github.

http://opc.olympus-imaging.com/en/tools/toolssdk/communications/

The spec above is not REST/JSON format but legacy CGI/XML format.
Unfortunately, Olympus do not provide any sample for HTTP access. 
I know some third party developers try to make their own library in the language other than Objective-C/Java (Android).

For example, the person below is working on Javascript:

https://github.com/oimou/opc-js

Please post your question to SO if you get in trouble with the specification.

Comment: Thank you I know have the beginnings of a Java app using the CGI/XML API, its absolutely fine even though its not the 'trendy' approach.  It's actually not too difficult. I hope to create a sample project and post on GitHub in the near future.

Comment: Having looked at this, it seems that the choice of RTP for live view, while theoretically a good technology, means that its quite hard to develop alternative SDK's as it means first developing RTP support.  As a result we are looking at an Android solution because Olympus have not provided a core Java library providing RTP support which the Android is built upon. It would have been much better if Olympus had not made the RTP layer a part of an Android SDK but had made it a more generally usable library.

Answer (score 1):

The documents linked above are really detailed, but it is missing the OPC version of HelloWorld.

The first thing you need to do is connect to the WiFi AIR-XXXX .

The Air acts as the DHCP server as well as WAP. It's IP is 192.168.0.10.

For the air to accept your HTTP communication you need to set your Agent and the content length.

```
'user-agent': 'OlympusCameraKit', 'content-length':'4096'
```

I use check connect mode as a wake up.

```
192.168.0.10/get_connectmode.cgi
```

You have to set it to record mode.

```
192.168.0.10/switch_cameramode.cgi?mode=rec
```

You enable live view.

```
192.168.0.10/exec_takemisc.cgi?com=startliveview&port=5555
```

Then you can take a picture.

```
192.168.0.10/exec_takemotion.cgi?com=newstarttake
```

I have a sample python controller for command line and web here: https://github.com/joemcmanus/a01

Happy hacking.

-Joe